# Unable to load DLL 'libdb2.so' when establishing a DB2 connection with .net core in docker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docker, db2, .net-core

How do I make the libdb2.so file visible to the DB2 package? I have verified that the package works in Ubuntu, but I cannot make it work inside Docker.

Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.0
#assume the built app is in /app from the build so that the entrypoint command runs in the correct path
WORKDIR /app

#need to specify db2 driver lib
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/app/db2Lib"

#move all the source code in local directory ./app into the container directory /app
COPY ./app .

RUN mkdir -p db2Lib

ADD db2Lib db2Lib/
ADD ./runImage.sh .


RUN chmod -R a+wrx runImage.sh

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["./runImage.sh"]
```

runImage.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
ls $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
dotnet app.dll
```

Upon running the image, I get the following prints in the console

```
#from ls $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
icc 
libDB2xml4c.so
libDB2xml4c.so.58
libDB2xml4c.so.58.0
libdb2.so
libdb2.so.1
libdb2clixml4c.so
libdb2clixml4c.so.1
libdb2o.so
libdb2o.so.1
#from echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/app/db2Lib
```

but when my application runs, I get the following error

> Unhandled Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL
>   'libdb2.so': The specified module could not be found.

As you can see, the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable properly points to the correct directory as the documentation instructs at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/96960515-2ea1-4391-8170-b0515d08e4da/entry/Instructions_for_downloading_and_using_DB2_NET_Core_provider_package?lang=en.

To double check that the environment variable is being set, I do

```
Console.WriteLine(Configuration["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"]);
```

which indeed prints

> /app/db2Lib

Comment: Do you use nuget packages for install db2 drivers?

Comment: May be check file permissions?

Comment: As I understand for linux you need to use other nuget package:  https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBM.EntityFrameworkCore-lnx (with -lnx postfix). And you can copy so from nuget package path $HOME/.nuget/packages/IBM.Data.DB2.Core-lnx/<version>/build/clidriver/lib

Comment: @mustaccio good suggestion. unfortunately i tried adding chmod -R a+wrx db2Lib and it still doesn't work. ls -l $LD_LIBRARY_PATH confirmed its files had -rwxrwxrwx

Comment: apologies. i am using https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBM.EntityFrameworkCore-lnx/1.1.1.101

Comment: @Simon Any luck? I am facing this today. My setup is similar to yours, same error. I also have the LD_LIBRARY_PATH set correctly.

Comment: @Botonomous it's an internal problem. the ibm team is working on a solution.

see https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=80fcd246-baed-418a-8590-a1b1e52fab98&ps=100&tags=&query=&filter=&sortBy=&order=asc

"We are looking into this issue and will update you once we have a working solution. Obviously, in Docker environment the values of LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not being picked up by the application."

Comment: @Simon Thanks for the reply. Hope they get to the fix soon. I am going to try some poking around and will report back here if I get out fixed.  Please do the same if you get yours working.

Comment: @Botonomous as a work around, we had to spin a node server for db2 connection and use it as an internal api

Comment: Anyone ever get this working?

Answer (score 3):

For any future reference here is the [blog](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/96960515-2ea1-4391-8170-b0515d08e4da/entry/Using_NET_Core?lang=en) which explains what is needed to make it work on Docker. The example is related to Console Application but should hold good for other types of applications also.
    In summary, you need to have libxml2.so.2.7.6 in the system. If not, it can be downloaded and kept in the lib folder. This libxml2.so.2 needs to be linked to libdb2.so

```
    ln <libpath>/libxml2.so.2.7.6 <libpath>/libxml2.so.2

In the application's DockerFile, these two entries should be there before the entry point
    ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="<libpath>"
    Env PATH=$PATH:"<libpath>/bin:<libpath>/lib"
    ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ConsoleApp1.dll"]
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 1):

For the latest version `3.1.0.400` I found out that the required `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is located in `/app/clidriver/lib` by executing the following in my Dockerfile:

```
RUN find / -name clidriver -type d
```

So I just installed the `libxml2` package

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libxml2-dev
```

and set the library path

```
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/clidriver/lib
```

It's also important to include the right packages in the csproj file depending on the environment! The `OS` variable is usefull here, so it will work on both Win/Linux systems:

```
<PackageReference Include="IBM.Data.DB2.Core" Version="3.1.0.400" Condition="'$(OS)' == 'WINDOWS_NT'"/>
<PackageReference Include="IBM.Data.DB2.Core-lnx" Version="3.1.0.400" Condition="'$(OS)' == 'UNIX'"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  Really appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @vishwa, the `libdb2.so` needs `libxml2.so`.  My `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk

ENV APP_DIR=/app \
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/bin/clidriver/lib:/app/bin/clidriver/lib/libdb2.so \
    PATH=${PATH}:/app/clidriver/bin:/app/clidriver/lib

RUN set -e; \
    mkdir -p ${APP_DIR}; \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y libxml2-dev;

WORKDIR ${APP_DIR}

COPY Pastdev.Example.App Pastdev.Example.App

RUN set -e; \
    dotnet build .; \
    dotnet publish --no-restore --no-build \
        -o ${APP_DIR}/bin \
        Pastdev.Example.App/Pastdev.Example.App.csproj

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/app/bin/Pastdev.Example.App.dll"]
```

I also wanted to be able to build and run on windows outside of docker so I set up my `.csproj` like this:

```
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(os)' == 'UNIX'">
    <PackageReference Include="IBM.Data.DB2.Core-lnx" Version="1.2.2.100" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(os)' == 'Windows_NT'">
    <PackageReference Include="IBM.Data.DB2.Core" Version="1.2.2.100" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could fix my project updating the following env variables:

```
ENV DB2_CLI_DRIVER_INSTALL_PATH="/app/clidriver" \
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/app/clidriver/lib" \
    LIBPATH="/app/clidriver/lib" \
    PATH=$PATH:"/app/clidriver/bin:/app/clidriver/lib"
```

and also installing this library libxml2:

```
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y libxml2
```

I've pushed my project to the following repo:

[https://github.com/renatomatos79/docker-netcore-db2-client-api/blob/main/Dockerfile](https://github.com/renatomatos79/docker-netcore-db2-client-api.git)