# Add PackageReference only on Linux for ASP.NET Core 3.1 csproj: List of csproj condition variables for the operating system?

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, db2, asp.net-core-3.1, csproj

I need to build a condition where one package is only included on Windows and another package only on Linux. [Nuget supports `Condition` attributes to include a `PackageReference` only in specific cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#adding-a-packagereference-condition). That's exactly what I need, but the example only checks the framework version with the `$(TargetFramework)` variable.

I need a variable like `$(OS)` but I don't know which variables exists and what's their contect to write correct conditions. For MSBuild I found a [list of well-known properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-reserved-and-well-known-properties?view=vs-2019) and [build macros (but for C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-160). It seems that `$(Platform)` is `Win32`, however I have no clue what it looks on Linux: Is it Linux? The distribution? Linux32/64?

For Windows I tried

```
<PackageReference Include="IBM.Data.DB2.Core" Version="3.1.0.400" Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'Win32'"/>
```

which doesn't work, I assume that this is only applied to C++ code and not C#.

I'm wondering that there must be a documentation of those variables for .NET Core with the avaliable values, sadly I can't find one.

#### Background: DB2

My app needs the `IBM.Data.DB2.Core*` package to access the database of a legacy application. The [IBM.Data.DB2.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBM.Data.DB2.Core/) package only works on Windows, where [IBM.Data.DB2.Core-lnx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBM.Data.DB2.Core-lnx/) works on Linux. If we use the win package on linux, it throws a [*Unable to load shared library 'db2app64.dll'* error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55466246/unable-to-load-shared-library-db2app64-dll). Since this app should run on Win and Linux, I'd like to make it ready for both platforms.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612790/different-nuget-package-based-on-operating-system

Answer (score 1):

[Using the process explorer, I was able to see the environment variables of Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31125227/3276634). Those variables are avaliable in the csproj file as `$(VARNAME)`. It contains a variable `OS` which is set to `Windows_NT` on Windows 10, so I could create a condition for Windows:

```
<PackageReference Include="IBM.Data.DB2.Core" Version="3.1.0.400" Condition="'$(OS)' == 'WINDOWS_NT'"/>
```

After I'd like to change to Alpine from my Docker base image, I ran into other issues and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53025008/3276634) which investigated that `OS` is set to `UNIX` on Linux systems, which leads me to the second condition:

```
<PackageReference Include="IBM.Data.DB2.Core-lnx" Version="3.1.0.400" Condition="'$(OS)' == 'UNIX'"/>
```

However, I'm still wondering not to found an official documentation about the avaliable variables in C#, this workaround has fixed my problem.

Comment: Appreciate it, this worked well for what I needed.